# Django runserver error when specifying port

Tags: django

I have recently become accustomed to doing the following in my django projects so that I can test bowser compatibility on various OS (i.e. non-linux):

```
$ sudo ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

This allows me to access the project through any machine on the network.

However, I just setup a new machine and this command issues the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
     from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

I understand that django is having trouble finding the module, what I don't understand is that plain old:

```
$ sudo ./manage.py runserver
```

Runs fine. All I am doing here is changing the port, surely? And, of course, it worked fine in the past.

**N.B.**
1. I am using Django 1.4
2. I have tried within a virtualenv and on system and I get the same result.
3. I do not have django installed system wide (just in virtualenvs)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know exactly why that doesn't work. Does it work if you run `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` (i.e. on a port >1024 without sudo)

Comment: I get the same error on system, and the following error in virtualenv: `Error: You don't have permission to access that port.`

Comment: Does it work if you explicitly call it with python: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: That works! Thankyou. Any explanation as to why `sudo` and `./manage.py` don't work?

Comment: @darwin-tech Sudo is for Global. If you try `sudo` inside virtualenv it won't consider the python packages you installed locally(`pip install`) to that virtualenv. Instead, `sudo` will check for python package that are installed *globally*. From the error, we can understand that you didn't install Django globally. Remove the `sudo`, and it will work fine. Don't use port 80; try 8000 or 8080. `(your_env)****@****$ **python manage.py runserver 8000**`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I guess the sudo command will run the process in the superuser context, and the superuser context lack virtualenv settings.

You may try to call the python binary at your virtualenv explicitly, for example:

```
sudo $(which python) manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

Make a shell script to set the virtualenv and call `manage.py runserver`, then sudo this script instead.

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/darwin/.virtualenvs/foo/bin/activate
cd /path/to/project/foo
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

Replace `/home/darwin/.virtualenvs/foo` with the root of your actual virtualenv and `/path/to/project/foo` with the root of your project.

Comment: Note that using sudo will NOT use your local environment's python, instead it will use your system's default python (you may miss your required packages)

Answer (score 8):

Here's another solution, instead of creating shell script, just specify which python executable you want to use in the command:

Assuming that your virtualenv container is called `.virtualenvs` and there's an env called `myproject` in it, this is command you have to write:

```
$ sudo ~/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

Comment: Execute that comand from inside the django project folde, where `manage.py` resides

Answer (score 1):

Building upon @Paulo_Scardine's anwser:

If you want to keep your virtualenv environment variables, you can add the `-E` option to the `sudo` command:

```
sudo -E $(which python) manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution, instead of creating shell script, just specify which python executable you want to use in the command:

Assuming that your virtualenv container is called venv in your project home directory, this is command you have to write:

```
sudo /home/mahome/PycharmProjects/sampleproject/venv/bin/python manage.py runserver 127.0.1.1:80
```

Answer (score -1):

Run
manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 
ie. run the server in different port and not the default port 80
while accessing the url use the port number

Comment: Not to grave dig, but this is seldom a "solution" as its bad for user experience. Use this only if its a tool solely for yourself. Asking users to specify the port number is a bad idea.