# Django: Error: You don't have permission to access that port

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, virtualenv

I'm very new to this whole setup so please be nice. 
On dev the command usually works with no errors but since I have been experimenting with different commands for Django someting has gone wrong.

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

I don't have permission to use this port anymore. I can use port 8080 but the website doesn't work when I add the port to the end of the usual host name in the url. When I used port 80 I never had to add :80 to the url anyway.

I had an error where I didn't have permissions to the log file but I changed the permissions on that file. It seems there is now many things I don't have permissions for.

Django 1.8.5. 
Using a virtual envirnment and I have 2 apps in the project.

Comment: sudo python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80

Comment: I don't understand your question. You don't use `runserver` with uwsgi.

Comment: And @mtt2p please don't recommend that; you're basically encouraging OP to use runserver for production.

Comment: Thanks @mtt2p that worked but why do I have to use sudo now? It used to work without sudo.

Comment: was it working without sudo on port 80?? @Helpme

Comment: It is not currently but it did yesterday @manojprashantk

Comment: You should **not** be doing this. You should **not** be running runserver on port 80; and you should **not** be using runserver anyway if you are using uwsgi. Please provide us proper details of how you are using uwsgi and why you think you need runserver.

Comment: I use runserver on dev. Not in producion. @DanielRoseman

Comment: So why do you need to run it on port 80?

Comment: Thats what I was told to do. If I use another port then I cant access the website. It must be setup to work like this before I started working on this. @DanielRoseman

Comment: Argh this makes no sense. If you're running the dev server, you access it on the default port which is 8000. And what does this have to do with uwsgi? You do not appear to be using uwsgi at all.

Comment: I misunderstood the way this works. Thank you for pointing that out. I have taken it out of the question. Please don't -1 me. @DanielRoseman

Comment: I dont understand why you're getting so upset @DanielRoseman. You're over-complicating this while making assumptions. Which is not helpful or productive. By default, django uses a development server, not a production server. It's a http framework for python. Not a server. Second, he can use any port according to the django documentation. In linux, it requires admin rights even though apache sets your port to 80 by default, but that's because its a deamon and has it's own user. That is a production server. Get your facts straight.

Answer (score 10):

If you're on Linux, you'll receive this error.

First and foremost, **Django does not have a production server**, just a very basic development server and uses port 8080 by default.

when you execute the command

```
python manage.py runserver
```

you tell django to start its development server and it runs so you can test your web app before deployment to a production server.

[Django Documentation -> django-admin -> Run Server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#runserver)

The way to access the server is to use your browser and plug in the URL in the address bar as so

```
localhost:8080
```

by default, most HTTP applications run on port 80 unless otherwise stated. For example, your MySQL server could run on port 3306 by default.

Basically, you can think of ports as old school telephone lines that connect you to whom ever your looking to communicate with.

There's nothing really special about any of this. You should probably play with bottle to get the basics down first; just a friendly suggestion.

You can dig in to the details on the website. While **not secure**, you can use `sudo` to run on port 80, but for security reasons you should avoid it.

@mtt2p mentions a [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/112795/how-to-run-a-server-on-port-80-as-a-normal-user-on-linux) post that does a great job of the why

I'm sure there's a way to tell the server to allow only local connections, but you should only use 0.0.0.0:80 when you want to show off your work to other people or see what your web app looks like on other devices.

**In the long run, `sudo` is just easier and quicker, but lazy and insecure.**

This is a link that explains it in the context of a virtualenv.

[Django runserver error when specifying port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520743/django-runserver-error-when-specifying-port)

The answer states

> I guess the sudo command will run the process in the superuser
> context, and the superuser context lack virtualenv settings.
>
> Make a shell script to set the virtualenv and call manage.py
> runserver, then sudo this script instead.

You should note that the answer explaining a virtualenv based context is also insecure. It should just be run as

```
sudo python manage.py runserver 80
```

not

```
sudo bash script-name
```

outside of a virtualenv. Doing so defeats the purpose of sand-boxing your application. If you ignore this, you'll be exposing yourself to a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

Answer (score 9):

Below helps to me to rectify same error:

in command line in windows:

net stop winnat

net start winnat

Answer (score 7):

I am in Xubuntu 20.04 version and I use this command (because I have an python env) :

```
$ sudo ~/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

And to know where is your envs python folder, I did :

```
$ which python
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

you need admin rights for port 80

Comment: add that sudo here (in your answer) also @mtt2p

Comment: Then can you tell me how to get admin rights for a port?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/112795/how-can-i-run-a-server-on-linux-on-port-80-as-a-normal-user

Comment: to inherit the environment you can use the -E option with the sudo command:
sudo -E python manage.py rumserver 0.0.0.0:80

Answer (score 1):

I set up a `virtualenv` called "aira" and installed `virtualenvwrapper` in the root environment (my virtualenvwrapper settings in /root/.bashrc are at the bottom). This reduces the number of sudo commands I need to cascade to `-c` together to get runserver working:

```
sudo sh -c "workon aira && python manage.py runserver --insecure 0.0.0.0:80"
```

If you've set up your django app's `virtualenv` without `virtualenvwrapper` you'll need to manually change to the correct directory and activate your `virtualenv` within the sudo command sequence. My virtualenv is called `aira` and I keep my virtualenvs in `/root/.virtualenvs`. My django project is in the ubuntu user's home directory:

```
sudo sh -c "source $HOME/.virtualenvs/aira/bin/activate && cd /ubuntu/src/aira/ && python manage.py runserver --insecure 0.0.0.0:80"
```

If you've installed django and your requirements.txt in the *system site packages* then you can use sudo to runserver.

```
sudo python manage.py runserver --insecure 0.0.0.0:80"
```

The `--insecure` option allows `staticfiles` to serve your static assets (images, css, javascript).

For completeness, here're my virtualenvwrapper configuration variables in `/root/.bashrc` on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
# python3 is used for virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3 

# *root* reuses the virtualenvs in *ubuntu*'s home directory
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=/home/ubuntu/src

source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: Ubuntu uses bash so instead of doing `sudo sh` you have to do `sudo bash`. Just a little change.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo ./venv/bin/python manage.py runserver 80`

Comment: Please include an explanation with your answer to help readers understand how this works, and solves the problem. You can click the edit button at the bottom of your answer to add an explanation. Additionally, you may find it beneficial reading [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Since this is the same as other answers [`python manage.py runserver`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42183067/7758804) or [`sudo ~/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66099100/7758804), I can only assume it was posted as a confirmation or "thank you".

Answer (score 0):

**Run these Commands:**

- sudo su
- pip3 install django
- python3 manage.py runserver 0:80

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same case as me and **your port was working before but suddenly stopped working** the most likely case is that the port has been taken by other service or that did not close properly.

In windows you can do:

> ```
> 1. windows+r and type cmd.
> 2. run: netstat -a -n -o
> 3. here you can see which PID has taken the port
> 4. for closing you can go to task manager (ctrl+alt+delete)
> 5. go to processes tab
> 6. look for the matching PID and stop the process
> ```

This was he working solution for me to make it work again in the usual port apparently other app I had hijacked the port.