# How to change 'localhost' url django

Tags: django, python-3.x, virtualenv, ubuntu-18.04

I want to play around with social-django authentication app. Iwant to add for login with facebook. For that I need to change my *127.0.0.1*  to something like *my-site.com*. I wanted to change */etc/hosts*, unfortunetely it doesn't exist.

I created hosts file using touch command and added *127.0.0.1 my-site.com* (nothing more) and restarted my computer. I tried *runserver* command and copy-pasted hostname above to the beggining of the link (my-site.com:8000) but it didn't work.

My django project runs on venv.

If you have any ideas on solving my problem, please share

(I've posted a similar question on superuser.com, but no one seemed to know a solution there, so I ask here)

**EDIT**
my settings py now look like this

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['my-site.com', '127.0.0.1']
```

But it still doesn't work

Comment: you can use `ngrok`

Comment: can you explain in detail how it is not working, are you getting any error while running `runserver` command. Did you add your hostname to `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in `settings.py` file ?

Comment: You don't need to change your domain, just use **localhost** and set `http://localhost:8000` or whatever port you're using as the domain in your facebook settings. You can do that as long as you're using a "Test App" on Facebook. You'll also be able to use "test users" instead of having to use real facebook accounts.

Comment: @JaspreetSingh I changed settings.py, but it still doestn work. On localhost, site loads normally, but whenI switch to _my-site.com:8000_ it's loading for a long time and then it displays firefox _PageNotFound_ message

Comment: @pawqo it looks like there is some issue with dns, maybe this will help https://askubuntu.com/questions/347152/why-is-the-etc-hosts-file-not-working

Comment: You can check out my solution for which you do need to specify the port at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48900718/how-can-i-change-django-runserver-url/68535442#68535442

Answer (score 7):

You can use localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 as one of the workaround.

Use this script:
`$ python manage.py runserver localhost:8000`

Comment: It works! Great! Does somebody know, may I add / change something in settings.py to get the same effect?

Answer (score 3):

if you are on Mac or linux :

- edit your /etc/hosts/ file and add

> 127.0.0.1 mysite.com

if you are on window:

- Go to C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts and add

> 127.0.0.1 mysite.com

---

Then flush DNS pushing system changes

- MacOS/Linux

```bash
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

- windows

1. Open the Command Prompt as an administrator. You can do this by searching for "Command Prompt" in the Start menu, right-clicking on it, and selecting "Run as administrator".
2. Type the following command and press Enter: `ipconfig /flushdns`

---

Then add to `settings.py`

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [‘mysite.com’]
```

---

Finally, start your django application and you should be able to access it. Note that you must access with port whatever it is, the port nowadays should be `8000` Hence full path would be `mysite.com:8000`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LocalTunnel](https://localtunnel.github.io/www/) ,it allows you to easily share a web service on your local development machine without messing with DNS and firewall settings.

Install Localtunnel globally (requires NodeJS) to make it accessible anywhere:

```
npm install -g localtunnel
```

Run django server using

> python manage.py runserver

and use the command line interface to request a tunnel to your local server:

```
lt --port 8000
```

It will give you a temporary url to use in any place,You can use that url in other sysytems too,the url will be live until the server is running in your system.
You can also use the temporary url in facebook setting for testing purpose.

Comment: and you must add the url in ALLOWED_HOSTS or add '*' in ALLOWED_HOSTS

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the file *settings.py* so that *my-site.com* is contained in the list of *ALLOWED_HOSTS*.

For security reasons Django needs to know what server names it servers, which is specified by ALLOWED_HOSTS. On Django's web site it states that:

> A list of strings representing the host/domain names that this Django site can serve. This is a security measure to prevent HTTP Host header attacks, which are possible even under many seemingly-safe web server configurations.

[Django Settings: ALLOWED_HOSTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts)

Comment: I  changed the settings.py according to your advie but it still does not work :(

Comment: no, it loads for a while and firefox retrns 404(when on 127.0.0.1 it works normally)

Comment: you need to figure out where the 404 came from, Django you are playing with or the real "my-site.com". If you are running Django via runserver there should be some messages coming out when firefox place a request. If nothing happens then it's clear that firefox is visiting the wrong site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to buy, or get for free, a DNS (you can get a subdomain from Noip for free).
You then  have to connect your domain to your router (search in the settings) and port forward your computer through the port you want. Now you will be able to visit "yourdomain.com" and you will get your django server.
Don't forget to add your domain to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
I wish it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Before everything, you need to add your localhost domain to ALLOWED_HOSTS variable in settings.py:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['my-site.com', '127.0.0.1', 'localhost']
```

If you use PyCharm as your IDE, you can edit your configuration settings as so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I posted a [7 step tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48900718/how-can-i-change-django-runserver-url/68535442#68535442) to achieve this with and without specifying the port, on a similar question for anyone still looking for a solution!