# Error message when I run my Django server with sudo. "ImportError: Couldn't import Django..."

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, linux

I have a Django server in our local environment that we run some scripts through.

I wanted to get rid of having to run it with the portnumber attached to the IP when i run the web-app. So instead of running it with port 8000 i want to run it with 80.

requirement.txt:

```
asgiref==3.6.0 
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1 
certifi==2022.12.7 
charset-normalizer==3.0.1 
Django==4.1.7 
idna==3.4 
oauthlib==3.2.2
requests==2.28.2
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
sqlparse==0.4.3 
urllib3==1.26.14
```

I found some sources (*) that said that i could run it with sudo to get rid of the initial:
'Error: You don't have permission to access that port.' message.

(*)[Django: Error: You don't have permission to access that port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37434247/django-error-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-that-port/66099100#66099100)

But when i run the command

```
sudo python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

i get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:   

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 20, in <module>  
    if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
  File "manage.py", line 12, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

The same thread had a solution where i specify where i run my .venv so i should run it with

```
sudo .venv/bin/python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

But i get the same error message as before.

When i run:

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

the output is empty, so i'm not sure what i should specify as my PYTHONPATH so that my root can find it when running the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are running your `Django` server with sudo, it changes the environment and you may not have access to your virtual env.

You could run a reverse proxy with `Nginx` so that you can run your `Django` server without recquiring root privilege:

first install `Nginx`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

then we create a `Nginx` configuration file for Django

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/my_django_project
```

put this inside:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your_server_domain_or_IP;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Dont forget to replace `your_server_domain_or_IP` with your server